# Quick way to clear all selections on a multiselect enabled <select> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, multi-select

Do I have to iterate through ALL the  and set remove the 'selected' attribute or is there a better way?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Simply find all the selected `<option>` tags within your `<select>` and remove the `selected` attribute:

```
$("#my_select option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

As of jQuery 1.6, you should use `.prop` instead of removing the attribute:

```
$("#my_select option:selected").prop("selected", false);
```

Comment: for multi select drop down , this will not clear displayed text.

Comment: But how do you clear displayed text?

Comment: $("#my_select option:selected").prop("selected", false); clears displayed text for me?

Answer (score 38):

In order to clear all selection, I am using like this and its working fine for me.
here is the script:

```
 $("#ddlMultiselect").multiselect("clearSelection");

 $("#ddlMultiselect").multiselect( 'refresh' );
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question.

Comment: What library is this for? Multiselect isn't part of jQuery or jQueryUI.

Comment: This is for bootstrap multiselect may be

Comment: worked for me : jQuery(".select-access").multiselect("clearSelection") "s" lowerCase.

Comment: he's refering to this plugin http://loudev.com/#usage
and btw "clearSelection" don't work now.
use "deselect_all" instead

Answer (score 3):

Shortest and quickest way to remove all the selection, is by passing empty string in jQuery .val() function :

```
$("#my_select").val('')
```

Comment: just a warning that if you have an option with value="", this method will select it so accepted answer is the way for you https://jsfiddle.net/yemgudc8/

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way to clear a multi-select or list box:

```
 $("#drp_assign_list option[value]").remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

In JQuery:

```
  $("#id option:selected").prop("selected", false);
  $("#id").multiselect('refresh');
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.clearAll').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown').val([]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="dropdown" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button class='clearAll'>Clear All Selection</button>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`$("#ddlMultiselect").val('').trigger("change");`

for multi-select drop-down, it will clear displayed text.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript,

You can use the list of all options of multiselect dropdown which will be an Array.Then loop through it to make Selected attributes as false in each Objects.

```
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
   if(list[i].Selected==true)
    {
       list[i].Selected=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is specifically asking for a way to do it without iterating over the whole list (which could get resource heavy if the list is long)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an empty array to unselect all the selection. Here goes an example. From [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)

> `val()` allows you to pass an array of element values. This is useful
>   when working on a jQuery object containing elements like , , and s inside of a
>   . In this case, the inputs and the options having a value that
>   matches one of the elements of the array will be *checked* or *selected*
>   while those having a value that doesn't match one of the elements of
>   the array will be *unchecked* or *unselected*, depending on the type.

```js
$('.clearAll').on('click', function() {
  $('.dropdown').val([]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="dropdown" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button class='clearAll'>Clear All Selection</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
```

https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/

Comment: This is the one that works if you're using bootstrap-select

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many solutions and came up with this.

Options and selections of the dropdown are cleared using this only

```
$("#my-multi option:selected").prop("selected", false);
$("#my-multi option").remove();
```

But the interface is not updated. So you have to do this

```
$('#my-multi').multiselect('rebuild');
```

Hence, the final code is

```
$("#my-multi option:selected").prop("selected", false);
$("#my-multi option").remove();
$('#my-multi').multiselect('rebuild');
```

***Suggestions and improvements are welcome.***

Comment: $('#my-multi').multiselect('rebuild');

this worked for me thanks bro :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#my_select option:selected").prop("selected", false).change();
```

Its clear value and display text as well.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Bootstrap multiselect dropdown by David Stutz

```
$('#selectId').multiselect('deselectAll', false);
```

But for some reason it does not work inside initialization method