# How to clear a multiple select dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quick way to clear all selections on a multiselect enabled <select> with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254736/quick-way-to-clear-all-selections-on-a-multiselect-enabled-select-with-jquery)

Dear All.

I have a problem. once i have a multiselect box and i want to clear all the contents of that when i clickon the reset button.

could you please provide me jquery for that?

Thanks.

Satya

Comment: by clear you mean remove selection?

Comment: You should post some of what you've tried, rather than just asking the community to provide you with code.

Comment: what you tried at your end till now show us some code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the future, you should post what you've tried so far - It gives people trying to answer your question a little more insight into what path you're taking, and where you might be going down the wrong path.

That being said, you can remove a list item from it's container with the `.remove()` method, like this:

```
$('#list option').each(function(index, option) {
    $(option).remove();
});
```

you can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9pzS/

and here's a version that uses the `.empty()` method to remove all of child items in the list: http://jsfiddle.net/y9pzS/1/

Note: there's a fair amount of ambiguity in your question.  Not sure if you're looking to clear out the entire container, or just remove the selected items.  This will remove *all* items from the select box.

Answer (score 13):

I assume you mean clear selection:

```
//for jQuery >= 1.6
$('select option').removeProp('selected');
//for jQuery < 1.6
$('select option').removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 8):

To unselect all items if using jQuery 1.6.1 or later:

```
$('#mySelect').children().removeProp('selected');
```

or for backwards compatibilty:

```
$('#mySelect').children().removeAttr('selected');
```

For simplicity's sake I'm assuming that your HTML is well formed and that your `select` only has `option` children.

Also, if the list is large and performance is an issue, `filter` the list so that you only change the ones that are actually selected - it's arguable whether it's simpler to simply deselect every option or only change the ones that need deselecting:

```
$('#mySelect').children(':selected').removeProp('selected');
```

[NB: using `:selected` in the second function call is (according to the jQuery docs) more efficient than making a single compound selector]

Answer (score 3):

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254736/quick-way-to-clear-all-selections-on-a-multiselect-enabled-select-with-jquery):

```
$("#my_select option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```