# bootstrap multiselect - De-select / Uncheck all options in a single click

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using [Bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) and I would like to add an option to uncheck all selected options. Please provide me with a solution for the same. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick way to clear all selections on a multiselect enabled <select> with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254736/quick-way-to-clear-all-selections-on-a-multiselect-enabled-select-with-jquery)

Comment: @L_7337 This is a bootstrap multiselect, it's different.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Try this

```
$("option:selected").prop("selected", false)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me too, What worked for me is

`$('#multi-select-dropdown').multiselect("deselectAll", false).multiselect("refresh");`

Answer (score 20):

You can use `.multiselect('refresh')` method as mentioned in the `bootstrap-multiselect` documentation [here](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods).

So, add an HTML button / icon next to the multi-select select list and then use the below code:

```js
$("#reset_client").click(function(){
  $('option', $('#select_client')).each(function(element) {
    $(this).removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
  });
  $("#select_client").multiselect('refresh');
});
```

```html
<select name="clients[]" multiple="multiple" id="select_client" style="display: none;">
    <option value="multiselect-all"> Select all</option>
    <option value="1">Client 1</option>
    <option value="2">Client 2</option>
    <option value="3">Client 3</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">Client 4</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="5">Client 5</option>
    <option value="6">Client 6</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="7">Client 7</option>
    <option value="8">Client 8</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Reset" name="reset_clients" id="reset_client" class="reset_button" title="Clear Selection">
```

Comment: Working for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Use below code to deselect all select item in multiselect bootstrap dropdown

```
$("#ddlMultiSelectId").multiselect('clearSelection');
```

Answer (score 9):

You can include a "select all" button, pushing that twice would "unselect all".
To do this add this option:

```
includeSelectAllOption:true
```

This will deslect all for a bootstrap multiselect based on a select element.

> ```
> function multiselect_deselectAll($el) {
>     $('option', $el).each(function(element) {
>         $el.multiselect('deselect', $(this).val());
>     });
> }
>
> $('.multiselect').each(function() {
>     var select = $(this);
>     multiselect_deselectAll(select);
> });
> ```

You could add an option by hand that says "Select all" and then when it's pressed call the reset function.

See:
https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/271

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the "deselectAll" method.

```
$("select.multiselect").multiselect("deselectAll", false);
```

It is important that you tell jQuery to target your "select's" only, otherwise it will fail. This is because the plugin adds something else with the same class name.

@L_7337 - This is not a duplicate of the post you link to. This post is about how to deselect all options, if you use [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

The other post, is how to deselect, from a normal multiselect option.

Best regards 
Rasmus

Answer (score 2):

If you have the below multi-select:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Choose Skills</label>
      <select id="DDL" name="selValue" class="selectpicker form-control"  multiple>
               <option value="1">One</option>
               <option value="2">Two</option>
               <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
  </div>
```

Then you can use the below jQuery to deselect all option on a click of a button:

```
$('#DDL').selectpicker("deselectAll", true).selectpicker("refresh");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#select_id option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Comment: @dhh, the user explains the scenario already, and there is already a selected answer which does not work. The answer I posted is just to correct the selected answer. The user has not given any code scenario that I can help him on how to make this work. Also, we are not here to do homework for people right? We just suggest the way/path to reach your goal. Thanks anyway for your precious comment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in a gitlab fork [here](http://gitlab.mmcs.sfedu.ru:82/dummer/itlabfork-bootstrap-multiselect/commit/2e93a99a5477b02d693105c3f34d480bee43fe08)

it says:

> Fixed trigger onSelectAll when deselecting Select All

Alternatively we can wait while [issue #752](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/752) will be resolved. It was raised only one month ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<div class="modal show" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Channel(s)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Collaborator(s)</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>              <div class="form-check row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 form-check-label" for="ListeningProject">Listening Project</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="ListeningProject" value="" type="checkbox" />
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 form-check-label" for="AccountName">Select:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="AccountName" multiple="" required="">
                  <option>A Company</option>
                  <option>B Copany</option>
                  <option>C Company</option>
                  <option>D Company</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$("#ListeningProject").change(function(){  //"select all" change
    var status = this.checked; // "select all" checked status
    $('#AccountName option').prop('selected', status);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, it works for me:

```
$('#dropdownID').val([]).multiselect('refresh')
```